# How to create an error or exception if the value entered is not in the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a program where in I want to create an exception or an error if the user types a wrong value or inputs a value that does not exist in the database. I am using a gridview control in this matter.

Here I can show you a code snippet:

```
Dim searchString as String
searchString = txtSearchAnnouncement
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Announcements (WHERE announcement LIKE '%" + searchString + "%') OR (sender_name LIKE '%" + searchString + "%') OR (date_posted LIKE '%" + searchString + "%') OR (announcement_status LIKE '%" + searchString)
```

Any comments/suggestions are well accepted..

Comment: Don't do string concatenation with `+`, eventually you will run into problems. Use the ampersand `&` instead. Also, for SQL use SQLParameters instead because this is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: You also have a typo in the end. This: `searchString)` should be `searchString & ")"` (I'm using `&` instead of `+`).

Comment: Why not use dropdown and show only the values present in the database?

Answer (score 3):

Just check if your query returns any valid values or not. If not, just display an appropriate message to the user.